# Errors when converting to postgres

Tags: playframework, slick, slick-2.0, playframework-2.3, play-slick

**Background**

- Play 2.3
- Slick 2.1
- Play-Slick 0.7
- Running in Typesafe Activator

I have a pretty basic Play and Slick-based application. Up to now I've been using the in-memory h2 database used by default in most of the examples.

In `application.conf` I have the following lines:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

If I use

```
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
```

for any code which interacts with the database, the application knows to pull in the defines in `application.conf` and the following happens when I run my application:

- evolutions.default/1.sql is created
- a new h2 database is instantiated in memory
- 1.sql is run on that db
- the application can interact with the db

**Problem**

I want to migrate to using a Postgres db, so I've changed `application.conf` to:

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb"
db.default.user=testuser
```

and I've added the following to my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  ...
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4"
)
```

However, if I write a test like the following:

```
import models._
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import play.api.db.slick.DB
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
import play.api.test.{FakeApplication, WithApplication}

class FooSpec extends Specification {    
  "DB" should {    
    "store Foos" in new WithApplication {    
      val foos = TableQuery[FooTable]    
      DB.withSession { implicit s: Session =>
        foos.insert(Foo("bar"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a few errors which I don't understand:

> [error] p.a.d.s.d.TableScanner$ - Got an error converting to DDL. Check whether the profile used for the Table/TableQuery is the same one used by DDL generation.
>
> [info] foospec
>
> [info] DB should
>
> [info] ! store Foos
>
> [error]   SlickException: JdbcProfile has no TypeInfo for type Int/INTEGER

(I have a stack trace for the error if needed, but I've left it out for now)

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly where, but you are importing different Slick drivers in different places. When artifacts taken from them get mixed up you get `SlickException: JdbcProfile has no TypeInfo for type Int/INTEGER`.

Comment: You were correct - although I wasn't actually referencing the old .scala file which imported the different database driver, it was still being imported into my test, hence this problem. Thanks for the pointer.